# Symantec Version Reg Query

Tags: windows-registry, batch-file, query

I'd be really grateful for some assistance with this, as it's blowing my mind.

All I want to do is pull the Version Number of Symantec, using the below code, which works in part, all except the gathering of the last part of the string, which I know is correct as I have something similar working in other batch files.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

--

```
@echo off 

@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set VersionReg = (
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\currentversion\public-opstate" /v "DeployRunningVersion"
)

echo %VersionReg%

SET Version=%VersionReg:~134,14%

echo %version%
```

--

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Is your version string really more than 134 characters long?

Comment: Run your batch file without the @echo off and [edit] to include the output ...

Answer (score 1):

Next `.bat` code snippet shows how-to grab `reg query` output to a variable using [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Mostly explained using `rem` comments.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_regKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\currentversion\public-opstate"
set "_regVal=DeployRunningVersion"

    rem my testing values in next 2 lines (remove them)
set "_regKey=HKCU\Control Panel\PowerCfg\PowerPolicies\3"  delete this 2 lines
set "_regVal=Description"                my testing values delete this 2 lines

for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
            reg query "%_regKey%" /v "%_regVal%" ^| findstr /I "%_regVal%"
    ') do (
            rem next 3 lines: debugging output could be removed
        echo value name "%%~G"
        echo value type "%%~H"
        echo value data "%%~I"
        set "_VersionReg=%%~I"
    )

SET "_Version=%_VersionReg:~12,26%"      delete this line and uncomment next one
rem SET "_Version=%_VersionReg:~134,14%"                      uncomment this line

    rem an empty line for output better readability 
echo(

    rem show result:   instead, you can use         ECHO "%_Version%" 
    rem or enable delayed expansion and use         ECHO  !_Version!
set _
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1142022.bat
value name "Description"
value type "REG_SZ"
value data "This scheme keeps the computer running so that it can be accessed from the netwo
rk.  Use this scheme if you do not have network wakeup hardware."

_regKey=HKCU\Control Panel\PowerCfg\PowerPolicies\3
_regVal=Description
_Version=keeps the computer running
_VersionReg=This scheme keeps the computer running so that it can be accessed from the netwo
rk.  Use this scheme if you do not have network wakeup hardware.
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%G`, `%H` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`|`, `&` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`%_VersionReg:~12,26%` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- ( `^` caret, double quotes in `set "varname=varvalue"` etc.)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)